# MySQL query won't execute in PHP script but works fine in MySQL Workbench

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using Hurl.It for testing so I know that the value I'm passing to the script is good and receiving the value in the PHP itself isn't the issue. But the query won't execute when triggered through PHP even though I can properly execute it in MySQL Workbench. Here is the code:

```
$UserName = $_POST['UserName'];

$getPermissionsQuery = "UPDATE Enrollment_Table.Scenario s, (SELECT p.School_ID, p.School_Name, p.School_Chancellor FROM Enrollment_Table.Schools p INNER JOIN
(SELECT a.User_ID, a.User_Name, b.Permission_ID, b.Permission_School FROM Enrollment_Table.Users a
LEFT JOIN Enrollment_Table.User_Permissions b ON a.User_ID = b.Permission_User_ID WHERE a.User_Name = '$UserName') q ON p.School_ID = q.Permission_School)
t SET s.Enrollment_Change_Scenario = 0, s.Tuition_Increase = 0 WHERE s.Enrollment_School = t.School_Name AND s.Campus = t.School_Chancellor";

$getPermissionsAction = mysqli_query($conn, $getPermissionsQuery);
```

Comment: that's because $UserName is just that in PHP which it is here: a String. You need to replace that with the username or use sql parameters

Comment: `I keep getting an error`, what is that error? Please always include errors with questions.

Comment: @JohnSmith, I've included $Username in a simpler test query in the same way, just inserting '$UserName' into the query itself, and that test query executes

Comment: @chris85 The query just isn't executing as I'm not seeing any database changes. It's not causing the php script to crash or anything like that

Comment: So there is no error? You are checking for errors?

Comment: There is no error I can find. I'm using mysqli_error($conn) to check and it returns nothing

Comment: Okay, and if you output `$getPermissionsQuery` it is the same as what you execute against the DB directly?

Comment: Exactly. I just now copied and pasted the query, replacing $UserName with an actual user and the query executed and had the desired effect on the DB

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: You should learn how to use parametrized queries instead of substituting variables into the SQL, to prevent SQL-injection. But that's probably not the problem here, unless `$UserName` contains a quote character.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: `replacing $UserName with an actual user`, why? The query should output as it should be executing.

Comment: That's the thing. It's not executing. And I generally use bound parameters and prepared statements but I'm just testing here.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to use mysqli_select_db($conn, $db).

This is odd because I only needed the $conn variable to execute other queries elsewhere in my project. I was using the same procedure here but for some reason that wasn't enough. Selecting the database made it work.